# Random Number: converting JavaScript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following line of code in javascript:

```
(Math.random() + "") * 1000000000000000000
```

which generates numbers like:

```
350303159372528000
```

I tried the same thing in PHP with this:

```
rand()*1000000000000000000
```

Which returns:

```
2.272e+21
```

I need to use PHP as the number generated will be stored as a SESSION variable and will be used by JavaScript later on.

**How do I get PHP to force the number to be an int rather than a float?**

---

EDIT PHP seems to struggle with this.

Would it work if I just generated the rand number in PHP saved it to the SESSION and then done the multiplying by 1000000000000000000 in JavaScript?

How would I go about this?

Comment: Theres no point on converting to a string and then back to a number again in your Javascript

Comment: There's a tiny bit more of that line which converts it back into a string, but I did not include it as I didn't think it was relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved the issue like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
 function RandNumber($e){


 for($i=0;$i<$e;$i++){
 $rand =  $rand .  rand(0, 9);  
 }
 return $rand;

 }

 echo RandNumber(18);
// Outputs a 18 digit random number

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend calling

```
PHP_INT_MAX
```

To see if your PHP installation can handle an integar that large. I'm guessing it can't which is why it is knocking it down to scientific notation.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest [converting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) your result to an int:

```
intval(rand()*1000000000000000000)
```

That said, see Kolink and Jeremy1026 answers for precision issues. If you only need an unique identifier, see Truth's answer.

**Update:** if you're using strings to represent your numbers, don't want or can't use an [arbitrary precision library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211345/working-with-large-numbers-in-php), and **don't stricly need** perfecly fair random numbers, you could generate smaller numbers and concat them together:

```
strval(rand()*999999999 + 1) . strval(rand()*1000000000)
```

(The `+1` is to avoid a leading zero in your result; note also that your number will never have a single digit, but every other number is possible)

For a random number with (exactly) 18 digits, you can also use [`str_pad`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) in the 2nd part, to fill it with leading zeros:

```
strval(rand(100000000,999999999)) .
    str_pad(strval(rand(0,999999999)), 9, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

Comment: PHP does not like that and ends up returning 0, seems like MAX_INT issue?

Comment: The docs linked above says: "Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the leftmost characters of the string." So it's more likely a string issue (integers would overflow instead AFAIK). See also [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) (about integer conversion in PHP)

Comment: I just tried telling it to be an integer and then evaluating it with intval and it still returns 0, any ideas?

Comment: Have you confirmed that indeed your PHP can handle integers this large? (a 64bit implementation can, a 32bit can't) I can only make further suggestions if you tell more about your requirements. If you really need big numbers, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211345/working-with-large-numbers-in-php), but I'm 99% sure there might be a simpler solution. What exacly will those numbers be used for?

Comment: You are a genious! That is such a clever way to get around the issue. Basically, this is for ad generation so I need 18 digit long randomish numbers, it does not have to be fair, just different most times.

Comment: Currently your method is generating too many digits is there any way to make it so it only generates a randomish number with 18 digits?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a unique identifier (which is what it looks like you're trying to do), please use PHP's `uniqid()` function.

Answer (score 2):

floor() / ceil() / round() / (int) / intval() will convert the number to int.
Also, rand() takes two arguments. If ints are supplied - it will return an integer

And printf() should take care of printing in the format you wish (printf('%d', $int) should do the trick)

Comment: Also note that [`getrandmax`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getrandmax.php) will tell the greatest value that can be returned (good to know if you're hitting the platform's limit in supported precision).

Comment: The author should have a look at [this thread too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1479823/1105527)