# Generate BIG random number php

Tags: php, random

I want to generate a number with 75 characters using PHP.

I have searched everywhere and got nothing, except for this: http://dailycoding.com/tools/RandomNumber.aspx

I do not think it is effective to grab it from that page.

What I have tried is this:

```
rand(1,9999999999999999999999999999999999999);
```

Comment: Are you doing math with the number, or just displaying a large number-like string (no maths)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479823/in-php-how-do-i-generate-a-big-pseudo-random-number

Comment: @DACrosby's question is crucial.  `rand()` returns an integer which has a max value of `2147483647`.  If you want to do any math, you'll need to leave it as an integer.  Otherwise, you can make a function that picks random numbers `0-9` and appends them to a string to make a large X-digit number.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just need the string(no maths)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
function bigNumber() {
    # prevent the first number from being 0
    $output = rand(1,9);

    for($i=0; $i<74; $i++) {
        $output .= rand(0,9);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: You are correct. fixed.

Answer (score 3):

```
function genRandomNumber($length = 15, $formatted = true) {
    $nums = '0123456789';

   // First number shouldn't be zero
    $out = $nums[mt_rand( 1, strlen($nums)-1 )];  

   // Add random numbers to your string
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length-1; $p++)
        $out .= $nums[mt_rand( 0, strlen($nums)-1 )];

  // Format the output with commas if needed, otherwise plain output
    if ($formatted)
        return number_format($out);
    return $out;
}

echo genRandomNumber();         // 7,825,104,236
echo genRandomNumber(14,false); // 11648596961188
echo genRandomNumber(25);       // 7,154,062,783,835,742,231,986,176
```

See here: http://codepad.org/yDvyo6MY

Answer (score 0):

PHP's rand() function may have as little as 15 bits on some platforms, so it's only good for 4 digits at a time. But since to don't actually need the numeric value of the total, call rand(0,9999) to get a 4-digit value, convert it to a string (you'll have concatenate "000" in front of it and then trim to 4 characters with substr() to get leading zeros), and add 4 characters at a time to a big string.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because, the biggest integer can be generated with a PHP 64 bits is 9223372036854775807. The biggest with a PHP 32 bits is 2147483647.

You can see most information on the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow).

If you want an equivalent, you can generate a string but you can't manipulate your integer.

Answer (score -3):

Here you go ...

```
function genRandomString($length = 75) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $string = '';    

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Why does my post get a -1 ? its the correct answer and @Aby said he didn't need it for any Math functions

Comment: I din't give you -1, but it might be because you number contains letters!