# How can I generate a secure random number of 159bits in php 5.5.9?

Tags: php, random

I need to do some operations with big numbers in PHP. I had to choose between [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.bc.php) and [gmp](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) which seem to be the main libraries available for this kind of stuff. I needed the inverse modulo method which is not available in the `bcmath` library. So I'm using `GMP`.

Now I need to generate a random secure number between 0 and 2^159-1. But :

- `gmp_random_bits` is only available in php >=5.6.3
- `gmp_random_range` is only available in php >=5.6.3
- `gmp_random` doesn't let me specify precisely the number of bit (and what is a bit per lamb and who works with this kind of unit ?)

I tried to generate the number with `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`. I can only use bytes count, but I gave it a try. Only issue :

- `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20)` returns a string
- `bindec(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20))` returns 0
- `hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20))` returns 0
- `gmp_import` is only available in php >=5.6.1

So, I gave up and tried to upgrade my php to php5.6. Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-different-upgrade-or-downgrade-php-version-in-still-supported) I did :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But if I run `phpinfo()`, the php version displayed is still 5.9.9.

Please, help ! I'm desperate. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you actually added your new php to your apache config? Do that, restart Apache (or NginX) and it should work.

Comment: Yep. You need to restart the webserver as well after updating PHP version.

Comment: I restarted apache with `service apache2 restart` but no luck. How am I supposed to add my php to my apache config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work (tested in 5.5.9):

```
// gmp_init will interpret argument as hexadecimal when first two chars are 0x or 0X
$g = gmp_init( '0x' . bin2hex( openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( 20 ) ) );
echo gmp_strval( $g );
```

This uses [`bin2hex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php).

`bindec()` is a bit confusing, in that it only accepts strings of 1s and 0s. But `bindec()` was not needed to begin with, since [`gmp_init()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-init.php) will directly accept a hexadecimal argument. `bindec()` will also output a float if the input exceeds `PHP_INT_MAX`, which leads to undesired results if input into `gmp_init()`. But since representing large numbers were the reason you wanted to use GMP, utilizing `bindec()` was out of the question to begin with.

<sub>Irrelevant, as per OP's comment:</sub>

<strike>Lastly, the order in which you tried to call `hexdec()`, `bin2hex()`, `bindec()`, in one of your examples:</strike>

```
hexdec(bin2hex(bindec(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20)))
```

didn't make sense, as this tried to first convert binary to decimal but then binary to hexadecimal.

But, as shown in my above example, merely using `bin2hex()`, which, contrary to `bindec()`, *does* accept raw binary data *and* does not have the `PHP_INT_MAX` limitation, should suffice.

As an alternative, you could also use [`unpack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php):

```
$g = gmp_init( '0x' . unpack( 'H*', openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( 20 ) )[ 1 ] );
echo gmp_strval( $g );
```

Comment: Sorry for `hexdec(bin2hex(bindec` I copied the previous line. I meant ` `hexdec(bin2hex(`. Your proposition seems promising. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: @Sharcoux Ah, I see. That makes more sense, yes. :) I'll edit that remark out then.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article about random strings and integers:
https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php

Restart apache service to be sure what php version you have

Please check your php version, 5.9 is not a valid php version,maybe you have 5.5.9 , valid releases are :https://secure.php.net/releases/ , you can use : `sudo php -v`

If the php version you have is not 5.6, and is not php7 and you want to use 5.6, remove completely your php and install php 5.6.

You can have php7 and 5.6 at the same time and switch:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Do you think that I should not use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` ?

Comment: if you want to generate random strings yes , if not you can make your own random number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789115/generate-big-random-number-php