# In PHP, can't figure out how to generate random integers between my max and min range

Tags: php, random, max

In PHP, I need to find a way to generate random integers between 1 and 46938003261

The rand function seems to be unable to generate numbers larger than 9 digits long, which is a problem for me given my 11 digit long max number.

rand (1 , 46938003261)

I realize this is a limitation of PHP on 32 bit systems, and I can verify that I have had the same issue using mt-rand instead of rand.

How can I generate a random integer between 0 and 46938003261 with PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a good solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504655/1696795

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In PHP, how do I generate a big pseudo-random number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479823/in-php-how-do-i-generate-a-big-pseudo-random-number)

Answer (score 0):

Append 2 numbers and concatenate them

```
rand (0 , 46938003261) + rand (10 ,100 )
```

But make sure you convert them to string and then add (?)

Another approach is to check the size of string before concatenating them.